# How are the variance of an estimate to $\int_Bf\:{\rm }d\mu$ and the deviation of $f$ from the mean $\frac1{\mu(B)}\int_Bf\:{\rm d}\mu$ related?

Tags: variance, monte-carlo, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space, $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued ergodic time-homogeneous Markov chain with stationary distribution $\mu$ and $$A_nf:=\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_i)\;\;\;\text{for }f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)\text{ and }n\in\mathbb N.$$ Suppose we're estimating an integral $$\mu f=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$$ for some $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$ and that $$\sqrt n(A_nf-\mu f)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2(f))\tag1$$ with $$\sigma^2(f)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\operatorname{Var}[A_nf].$$

> Assume that the support $B:=\{f\ne0\}$ is "small", but $\mu(B)>0$. Now let $$f_B:=1_B\left(f-\frac{\mu(1_Bf)}{\mu(B)}\right).$$ Instead of $\sigma^2(f)$ we could consider $\sigma^2(f_B)$ which, by definition, should tell us something about the deviation of $f=1_Bf$ from its [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function).
>
> If our concern is the minimization of the asymptotic variance of our estimation of $\mu f$, does it make sense to consider $\sigma^2(f_B)$ instead of $\sigma^2(f)$? How are $\sigma^2(f_B)$ and $\sigma^2(f)$ related?

### **Background**:

My actual concern is that I need to estimate $\lambda(hf)$ for a variety of $\mathcal E$-measurable $h:E\to[0,\infty)$, where $\lambda$ is a reference measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ so that $\mu$ has a density $p$ with respect to $\lambda$ and $\{p=0\}\subseteq\{f=0\}$. Now the support $E_0:=\{p>0\}\cap\{h>0\}$ is very "small" and you may assume that $h=1_{\{\:h\:>\:0\:\}}$. I want to estimate $\lambda(hf)$ using the [importance sampling estimator](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf).

Say $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is the chain generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with target distribution $\mu$, $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is the corresponding proposal sequence and $Z_n:=(X_{n-1},Y_n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. If the proposal kernel is denoted by $Q$, we know that $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has stationary distribution $\nu:=\mu\otimes Q$.

> Now, in light of the special form of the to be estimated integral $\lambda(hf)$, I thought it might be tempting to consider the Markov chain corresponding to the successive times of its returns to the set $E\times E_0$. To be precise, let $\tau_0:=0$ and $$\tau_k:=\inf\left\{n>\tau_{k-1}:Y_n\in E_0\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N.$$ Assuming that $E\times E_0$ is a recurrent set for $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, we know that $\left(Z_{\tau_k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is again an ergodic time-homogeneous Markov chain with stationary distribution $$\nu_0:=\frac{\left.\nu\right|_{E\times E_0}}{\nu(E\times E_0)}.$$

I wondered whether it makes sense to build an estimator using $\left(Z_{\tau_k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ instead of $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ or if this would gain nothing.

Comment: I notice you have posted many questions that get no answers--or even comments. They look like questions that many people on this site might be interested in and ought to be able to answer, so I would suggest--somewhat speculatively--that their failure to attract attention may be due to the extremely abstract ways in which you frame them. The use of more conventional terminology, providing some context or concrete examples, and including some explanations might help you get some answers more than bounties will.

Comment: @whuber - I have been thinking of writing a similar comment for some time now.  For example, as near as I can tell without spending some considerable time on it, this question could be rephrased and asked in four, maybe five, nontechnical sentences, with little or no math - making it completely accessible to the entire community... on further thought, maybe two or three sentences.

Comment: "I have a function of a random variable, which function takes on the value 0 over a non-trivial part of its domain.  When I am trying to come up with a minimum variance estimate of the mean of the function, does it make sense to consider the variance over just the part of the domain where the function $\neq 0$?   How does this relate to the variance of the estimate over the whole domain?"   might be an accessible approximation, if I've understood the question correctly (which I may well not have.)

Comment: What does $\mu(1_Bf)$ mean? You mean $E[1_Bf]$ instead?

Comment: @Michael - yes, but with the added (irrelevant) information that the expectation is with respect to the probability measure $\mu$.

Comment: (Assuming the above was a typo.) If you consider the iid case (trivial case of Markov chain), then $\sigma^2(f_B) > \sigma^2(f)$. Basically, you have replaced $E$ by $B$---or, equivalently, considered the conditional mean $E[f|B]$ and conditional variance $\sigma^2(f_B)$ instead of $E[f]$ and $\sigma^2(f)$. Empirically, this means you are discarding all the sample where $f = 0$. I don't see a statistical reason to do this.

Comment: With your condition that $\mu(B)$ is "small", you're discarding most of the sample.

Comment: @Michael - it depends upon whether the OP actually knows $\mu(B)$ a priori; if so, it's better to discard the part of the sample where $f=0$ because all that contributes is , in effect, downweighting $E[f|f>0]$ by the observed probability that $f>0$, but if you know $P(f>0)$ a priori, it's better to use it than the sample probability.

Comment: @Michael $\mu g:=\int g\:{\rm d}\mu$ (which is the expectation of $g$ wrt $\mu$ if you like). So, $\mu(1_Bf)=\int_B\:f{\rm d}\mu$.

Comment: @jbowman I don't know $\mu(B)$.